# plotting interactive Dendrogram with an unequal Heatmap using plotly python in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, heatmap, plotly-python, dendrogram

I'm trying to plot an **interactive** **dendrogram** with an **unequal heatmap** on jupyter notebook using Plotly package that would [look like this one](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Ejackp/6748/dendrogram-heatmap/).
[image: What I'm trying to plot]

My example data called *dataHeat_arr* is numpy.ndarray, which has 75 rows (samples called S0 till S74) and 100 columns (Metabolites  called M0 till M99) and available in the [link](https://github.com/TalWac/stakoverflow-Qustion).

In the [link](https://github.com/TalWac/stakoverflow-Qustion) there are 3 csv files.

1. dataHeat_arr.csv - the numpy.ndarray 75*100
2. name_molec.csv - list of metbolite named M0, M1,... till M99
3. Samplenum.csv - list of samples named S0, S1,... till S74

I based my code on the example from [her](http://Plot%20a%20Dendrogram%20with%20a%20Heatmap) and made some changes since my the heatmat is unequale.

Also tried questoins [Plotly clustered heatmap (with dendrogram)/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66547583/plotly-clustered-heatmap-with-dendrogram-python)

I do not know what I'm doning worng by the finale figure is missig the heat map.
only when ploting with equale heatmap I manage to plot the heatmap with the dendrogram.

her is my code.

**Import packges:**

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string 
from itables import init_notebook_mode
from itables import show
import cimcb_lite as cb
import plotly.graph_objects as go
init_notebook_mode(all_interactive=True)
```

**Initialize figure by creating upper dendrogram:**

```
# name the samples S0 till S74

# Samplenum & name_molec are csv files in the link of Github and should be treated as lists
labels = Samplenum
dataHeat_arr_t= np.transpose(dataHeat_arr)

# Initialize figure by creating upper dendrogram
fig = ff.create_dendrogram(dataHeat_arr, orientation='bottom', labels=labels)

# fig = ff.create_dendrogram(dataHeat_arr_t, orientation='bottom', labels=name_molec[:100] ) ,labels=name_molec[:100]

for i in range(len(fig['data'])):
    fig['data'][i]['yaxis'] = 'y2'
```

**Then Create Side Dendrogram:**

```
# Create Side Dendrogram

dendro_side = ff.create_dendrogram(dataHeat_arr_t, orientation='right' ,labels=name_molec[:100])
# dendro_side = ff.create_dendrogram(dataHeat_arr, orientation='right', labels=labels)
for i in range(len(dendro_side['data'])):
    dendro_side['data'][i]['xaxis'] = 'x2'
     
# Add Side Dendrogram Data to Figure
for data in dendro_side['data']:
    fig.add_trace(data)
```

**Create Heatmap:**

```
heatmap = [
    go.Heatmap(
        x = name_molec[:100],
        y =labels ,
        z = dataHeat_arr,
        colorscale = 'Cividis'
    )
]
```

**Add Heatmap Data to Figure:**

```
for data in heatmap:
    fig.add_trace(data)
```

**Now layout:**

```
# Edit Layout
fig.update_layout({'width':1500, 'height':750,
                         'showlegend':False, 'hovermode': 'closest',
                         })
# Edit xaxis
fig.update_layout(xaxis={'domain': [.15, 1],
                                  'mirror': False,
                                  'showgrid': False,
                                  'showline': False,
                                  'zeroline': False,
                                  'ticks':""})

# Edit xaxis2
fig.update_layout(xaxis2={'domain': [0, .15],
                                   'mirror': False,
                                   'showgrid': False,
                                   'showline': False,
                                   'zeroline': False,
                                   'showticklabels': False,
                                   'ticks':""})

# Edit yaxis
fig.update_layout(yaxis={'domain': [0, .85],
                                  'mirror': False,
                                  'showgrid': False,
                                  'showline': False,
                                  'zeroline': False,
                                  'showticklabels': False,
                                  'ticks': ""
                        })

# Edit yaxis2
fig.update_layout(yaxis2={'domain':[0.852, 0.975],
                                   'mirror': False,
                                   'showgrid': False,
                                   'showline': False,
                                   'zeroline': False,
                                   'showticklabels': False,
                                   'ticks':""})

fig.show()
```

for some reason the plot looks like that:

[image: dendrogram without heatmap]

Any idea/ hint will be usfull and appriciated!

Answer (score 1):

The correct code to plot heatmap with dendrogram on both y-axis an x-aixs:

**Initialize figure by creating upper dendrogram:**

```
Samplenum = ["S" + str(x) for x in idx]
labels = Samplenum
dataHeat_arr_t= np.transpose(dataHeat_arr)
# Initialize figure by creating upper dendrogram

# The line below was changed comparing to my question 
fig = ff.create_dendrogram(dataHeat_arr_t, orientation='bottom', labels=name_molec[:99] )


for i in range(len(fig['data'])):
    fig['data'][i]['yaxis'] = 'y2'
```

**Create Side Dendrogram**

```
# The line below was changed as well comparing to my question 
dendro_side = ff.create_dendrogram(dataHeat_arr, orientation='right', labels=["S" + str(x) for x in idx])
for i in range(len(dendro_side['data'])):
    dendro_side['data'][i]['xaxis'] = 'x2'
    
    
# Add Side Dendrogram Data to Figure
for data in dendro_side['data']:
    fig.add_trace(data)
```

**Create Heatmap:**

```
heatmap = [
    go.Heatmap(
        x = name_molec[:99],
        y =labels ,
        z = dataHeat_arr,
        colorscale = 'Cividis'
    )
]
```

**These 4 lines are new ( were not in my question):**

```
heatmap[0]['x'] = fig['layout']['xaxis']['tickvals']
heatmap[0]['y'] = dendro_side['layout']['yaxis']['tickvals']


# to tickes text on y-axis as well
fig['layout']['yaxis']['ticktext'] = np.asarray(labels)
fig['layout']['yaxis']['tickvals'] = np.asarray(dendro_side['layout']['yaxis']['tickvals'])
```

Most of the layout code stays the same but :`showticklabels': True`

```
# Edit yaxis
fig.update_layout(yaxis={'domain': [0, .7],
                                  'mirror': False,
                                  'showgrid': False,
                                  'showline': False,
                                  'zeroline': False,
                                  'showticklabels': True,
                                  'ticks': ""
                        })
```

The output looks more like the picture at beginning of my question.

[image: my finale plot]